# Outline Bold text font on website? how to fix it (Corrupted font)

Tags: browser, fonts, outline, corrupt

For a couple of months, I have had an issue with bold fonts on any website regardless of the web browser in use. All Header, titles, or any font with `<b>` or `<strong>` tags appear with an outline effect with made it impossible to read.

Here are some screenshots of the issue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was with the **Helvetica Neue** font family with has 2 bold-outline font types on it. Thus, any header, title, or text within the `<b>` or `<strong>` tag always appears with the outline.

By **removing** this **Helvetica Neue** font family the issue was completed fixed in my system.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Delete** the **Helvetica Neue** font family and the issue will be gone for goods.